# A subgroup of $\langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle$ containing two relatively prime integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading a first course in algebra, and there is a sentence that says:

> "Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle$ containing two relatively prime integers."

If I am not mistaken, all subgroups of $\langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle$ are of the form $\langle n\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle$, and so they cannot contain any two relatively prime integers. Only such a subgroup can be $\langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle$ itself. Am I right? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It also falls under the case of $\left< n\mathbb{Z} , + \right>$, when $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $p,q \in H$ are coprime, then there exist $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1=up+vq$, hence $1 \in H$. Therefore, $H= \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a subgroup $\rm\:  G\subseteq \langle \mathbb{Z}, +\rangle\:$ is generated by the gcd of its elements (and the gcd $=1$ if $\rm\:G\:$ contains two coprime elements).